# One physical monitor but system sees two

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I believe that my computer was attacked by an unknown virus. I have managed to fix majority of the problems one still stand (or it could have been the only one). I physically have one monitor plugged into my graphics card, but the system is seeing two. This was a major problem due to the fact the it booted up on the 2nd screen not allowing me to see icons, programs, screen resolution options, startup, ALT+CTRL+DEL functions, ect, ect. I ended up having to find and drag the resolution window to be able to set screen 2 as default screen. How can I remove the impostor screen? Here are some screen shoots on the subject.

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to remove the monitor with the "remove display" which only appears for invalid/disconnected displays

Comment: Do not see that option.

Comment: You selected the display, in the drop down menu, right?  I promise you, [it is there](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-you-delete-a-duplicate-display-in-screen/412e5c6a-d5a9-415b-ae1c-7e943b6f2745), do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the graphics card with my own two eyes it seems like a 2nd cord is now running to my monitor, after removing one of the cords this has fix the issue.